# Selecting a node that follows a given node

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I have to use DOM manipulation and XPath to pull data out of an iTunes Library XML file which is formatted as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Tracks</key>
    <dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>203</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Winter</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>Daughter</string>
            <!-- etc -->
            <key>Play Count</key><integer>2</integer>
            <key>Skip Count</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            Another set of track data, etc...
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I need to be able to pull out and store bits of data from this file and store them in arrays.
For example I'd like to store all the track names in one array, all the artist names in another, but I don't want to store other values such as play/skip count.

I know that XPath works like this (as demonstrated in the switch statement below) for getting to the right position, but the keys aren't always in the same position. I am effectively looking for a way to perform a lookbehind assertion based on the value of the preceding  value.

```
XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("/plist/dict/dict/dict");
NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
StringBuilder outputString = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 1; i <= nl.getLength(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        String label = "";
        switch (j) {
            case 0: expr = xPath.compile("/plist/dict/dict/dict["+i+"]/key[2]/text()");
                    //Append this value to TRACKNAME array with expr.evaluate
                    break;
            case 1: expr = xPath.compile("/plist/dict/dict/dict["+i+"]/key[3]/text()");
                    //Append this value to ARTIST array with expr.evaluate
                    break;
            case 2: /* ... */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your xml code is correct, you can try this solution:

```
/plist//dict["+i+"]/key[contains(text(),'Track ID')]/following-sibling::*[1]
```

It's making condition for key element - if contains text (f.e. 'Track ID'), find the first sibling element - in this case integer with value 203.

Using star after following-sibling gives you ability to catch every first element with no interest if it's integer or string element.